# How to understand the "align" attribute in WebAssembly?

Tags: webassembly

Why do those "load" and "store" operators need an "align" attribute, and how does it work with memory alignment?

BTW, why do we need this operator since the underlying system will do memory aligning for us automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a promise to VM that `(baseAddr + memarg.offset) mod 2^memarg.align == 0` where `baseAddr` is argument form stack.

In other words, we virtually split our memory by blocks with size `2^memarg.align` bytes and promise VM that our actual address (`baseAddr + memarg.offset`) will be at the start of any block, not in the middle.

Since the maximum value of `memarg.align` is 3 size of a block (in bytes) could be on of {1, 2, 4, 8} (1 = 2^0, .., 8 = 2^3).

Also, you can find a good detailed explanation [here](https://rsms.me/wasm-intro#addressing-memory).

Comment: It should be mentioned that the promise can be broken and unaligned loads, even with an alignment set on the instruction, are allowed. The WebAssembly/testsuite test in `address.wast` of `32_good5` confirmed this for me.

Answer (score 2):

The use of alignment is detailed in the spec:

> The alignment `memarg.` in load and store instructions does not affect the semantics. It is an indication that the offset `ea` at which the memory is accessed is intended to satisfy the property `ea mod 2^memarg.=0`. A WebAssembly implementation can use this hint to optimize for the intended use. Unaligned access violating that property is still allowed and must succeed regardless of the annotation. However, it may be substantially slower on some hardware.

There is no other semantic effect associated with alignment; misaligned and unaligned loads and stores still behave normally, it is simply a performance optimisation.

Comment: That quote in the spec is what brought me here, because I'm not smart enough to understand it :-(. What is being aligned? Why is it important to align it? Can't it be determined automatically?